# Displaying contents of ArrayList into properly formatted JSON for Java Jersey REST API

Tags: java, json, api, arraylist, jersey

I am building a Restful API that will send a response in JSON format. The data I want to send is in an arrayList. The simple way to do it seems like to convert the arrayList to JSON as there is a built-in toJSONString(), but that call converts it into a JSON strong with a lot of forward slashes, ex: {\"value1\":95,\"value2\":\"275\"}. I would like to convert it into a normal JSON string suitable for REST API, ex: {"value1" : "30", "value2", "65" }. Is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: Largely depends on the library or framework you're using for your RESTful service.

Comment: As @Makoto says, usually the framework you use will handle the transformation of your List into a proper JSON Array.

Comment: Looks like you have serialized the list twice

Comment: We are using the jersey library

Comment: Please show the code that is producing this.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use annotation '@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)' above the method which is returning the ArrayList.

For example:

Imagine we have a Model class 'Message':
Filename: Message.java

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Message {

    private long id;
    private String message;
    private Date created;
    private String author;

    public Message(){

    }

    public Message(long id, String message, String author){
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
        this.created = new Date();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

}
```

Then we have a MessageService:
FileName: MessageService.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MessageService {

    private Map<Long, Message> messages;

    public MessageService(){
        messages.put(1L, new Message(1, "Hello Stackoverflow", "Kevin"));
        messages.put(2L, new Message(2, "Hello Jersey", "Kevin"));
    }

    public List<Message> getAllMessages(){
        return new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
    }
}
```

At last, you will have a resource file which actually contains the method to return your ArrayList:
Filename: MessageResource.java

```
@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {

    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Message> getMessages(){

        return messageService.getAllMessages();
        //This method will return your ArrayList as JSON.
    }
}
```

Then just call the MessageResource Class from URL:

http://localhost:8080/kevinswebapi/messages

Note: localhost:8080/kevinswebapi is your Root path

I hope this helps...